# How to encrypt password in Python pysftp?

Tags: python, encryption, sftp, pysftp

I am using a Python script with the pysftp module to connect to SFTP server.

Apparently I can pass a SFTP password explicitly which I don't like.

My question: How could I replace the password for an encrypted one to avoid someone from being visible to the world?

Comment: The password should not be visible *on the wire* if you are using sftp.  In any case, at some point you will need to know the unencrypted password in order to encrypt it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the solution for this issue. It works  for me.
Instead of using explicit text of password I first encode it and put incoded form into the script.

Like this:

```
import base64

## To encrypt:
base64.b64encode("XYZ")
## you got 'WFla'

## To decrypt:
base64.b64decode("WFla")
# you got 'XYZ'
```

Comment: base64 is not an encryption in any way. It is merely an encoding to avoid special characters, for when you need to transfer or store arbitrary data as text. It's like saying I didn't give you the word "abc" when I told you "alfa bravo charlie".

Answer (score 1):

The standard method of keeping keys and passwords not visible to the world is not to store them somewhere world readable. That often means to not put them in your scripts, but configuration files such as [netrc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/netrc.html), which in turn are set to readable only by you. A more modern alternative is [keyring](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyring) services such as kwallet.

In addition, SSH (and its subprotocol SFTP) supports authentication using assymetric key cryptography. By using an [authentication agent](http://paramiko-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/agent.html), you can keep these keys in a separate process, so your script does not need the ability to decrypt or store them in the first place.

Both SSH agents and keyring services support encrypting the key storage itself, though whether this is done (and where) is hidden from the program that requests keys from them.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you do not want the password to be visible in code or configuration file? There's no way to encrypt anything in a way that allows automatic decryption. All you can do is to obfuscate the password, but not really encrypt it. If anyone can access your code he/she can always reverse-engineer your "encryption".

Comment: Martin. You are correct. Let call it obfuscate  .... My goal was not to encrypt password but make not readable if someone open python script. How could I obfuscate it? Thanks

Comment: Well ... I found the solution for my issue. I used base64 module and it served my need. I understand that anyone could decode it but my goal was just to hide it from being readable in python text file. Thanks for all suggesions. I'm all now

Comment: @susja Post it as an answer and accept it to close this question.

Comment: Martin Prikryl - I didn't get your advice. I already posted the answer and accepted it ... not clear what you meant ..

Comment: @susja Good! Though note that you did so after (Sep 26 at 19:27) I posted the comment (Sep 26 at 14:57)